# RangeHTML Body. How do I include my Header

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

So, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, I can't seem to get my header in my range. only the last line of data entered. However, I want both the header and the last line of Data entered.

```
Public Function ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(rInput As Range) As String
    'Declare variables
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim strReturn As String
    'Define table format and font
    strReturn = "<Table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>  " & "<Table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>  "
    'Loop through each row in the range
    For Each rRow In rInput.Rows
        'Start new html row
        strReturn = strReturn & " <tr align='Center'; style='height:14.00pt'> "
        **For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
            'If it is row 1 then it is header row that need to be bold**
            If rCell.Row = 1 Then
                strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>" & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'><b>" & rCell.Text & "</b></td>"
            Else
                strReturn = strReturn & "<td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>" & rCell.Text & "</td>"
            End If
        Next rCell
        'End a row
        strReturn = strReturn & "</tr>"
    Next rRow
    'Close the font tag
    strReturn = strReturn & "</font></table>"
    'Return html format
    ConvertRangeToHTMLTable = strReturn
End Function
```

---

```
Function EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow() As String
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = EmailData
    
    With Target
        .EntireRow.Hidden = msoTrue
        .Rows(1).Hidden = msoFalse
        .Rows(.Rows.count).Hidden = msoFalse
        .EntireRow.Hidden = msoFalse
    End With
    EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow = ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(Target.Rows(Target.Row.count))
End Function
```

Comment: Which range do you hand over to this function? Is in this range the header included?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you posted in the comment.

Comment: What error? Are the Ranges _Target_ (and _EmailData_ see your last question) set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The first line hides all of Target.
The second line unhides row 1.
The third line unhides the last row.
The fourth line unhides the whole table.

```
With Target
    .EntireRow.Hidden = msoTrue
    .Rows(1).Hidden = msoFalse
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).Hidden = msoFalse
    .EntireRow.Hidden = msoFalse
End With
```

Irrespective of what's hidden this line only takes the last row (`Row` should be `Rows`).
`ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(Target.Rows(Target.Rows.Count))`

Try removing the `With...End With` block and use this as the last line:

```
EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow = ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(Union(Target.Rows(1), Target.Rows(Target.Rows.Count)))
```

This returns the string:

```
<Table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>  <Table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>   <tr align='Center'; style='height:14.00pt'> <td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>Header 1</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>Header 2</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>Header 3</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>Header 4</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>Header 5</td></tr> <tr align='Center'; style='height:14.00pt'> <td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>LastRow 1</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtex
t 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>LastRow 2</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>LastRow 3</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>LastRow 4</td><td valign='Center' style='border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:1.05pt'>LastRow 5</td></tr></font></table>
```

Original table:
[image]

HTML Image:
[image]

Comment: So ive adjusted the line EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow = ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(Union(Target.Rows(1), Target.Rows(Target.Rows.Count))) .... and that definitely helped thank you. however, when I went to remove the End With it gave an error after compiling, said it expected the End With statement.

Comment: Where would I add the "Return the String" line?

Comment: If you only removed the `End With` then it would return an error.  Remove the whole block - from `With Target` to `End With` and all lines between.

Comment: The _Return the String_ part is what your `ConvertRangeToHTMLTable` function returns when it's passed the first and last row.  I just pasted that into a text file and saved as HTML.  I guess you'll use it as the body of an email.  `EmailObject.HTMLBody = the return string`